# Porta serial COM

Tags: c#, mysql, arduino

Estou tentando executar um código a cada determinado tempo, onde ele pega o valor enviado pela porta COM do Arduíno, imprime em uma textbox e logo apos gera um insert no banco mysql.

So que ele ler o que foi enviado pela porta COM e não executa o insert. Me ajudem.

```
 private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Open();
        string entrada = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        serialPort1.Close();
        txtIDTag.Text = entrada;

        if (txtIDTag.Text == "Gol")
        {
            string sql = "insert into tcc (Carro,Placa,Fabricante,Ano,Cor,Status,Data) value ('" + txtIDTag.Text + "','SCD - 4365','VW','2010','PRETO','NOVO', NOW())";

            comando.CommandText = sql;

            conexao.Open();

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conexao.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Dados cadastrados com sucesso.");

            txtIDTag.Text = "";
        }}
```

Tentei tirar o IF ai ele executou.

Comment: Por que não executa? Porque o texto é diferente de Gol, porque não consegue conexão com o banco ou porque dá erro no insert?

Comment: Ja testei as duas tags que tenho. A que esta como gol e a outra que definir como palio. O problema é que não da insert com nenhuma das duas.

Comment: Mas na *textbox* aparece corretamente? O que aparece? Tem certeza que não existem caracteres a mais na string? Por quê não faz o *if* utilizando o valor de `entrada`?

Comment: Esta correto sim. Fiz o que o colega Rodrigo falou. Coloque o sinal de diferente e ele executou corretamente. Não sei explicar o motivo. Alguém teria alguma opinião de como corrigir?

Comment: Ele não esta fazendo certo não. ta pulando o if e executa o que tem dentro. Coloquei dois ifs agora e ele so executa o que ta dentro pulando os if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente é pq o retorno da porta serial é feito em byte, pelo menos em Java é assim, tente achar algo para concatenar as informações. Pois o retorno passa da seguinte forma

Byte G ->
Byte O ->
Byte L

então se você comparar só o G talvez funcione.